# too many arguments - function with int argument

Tags: c, function, arguments

This code is the part of the program, which checks the row of a 3x3 Matrix.
The Values for the matrix as 'matrix[row][col]' and N as '3' is previously defined.

Compiling the Code gives something like:

```
error_handler.c:20:3: error: too many arguments to function ‘check_row’
```

The actual code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "globals.h"

void check_row(void); //Prototype

bool check  (void)
{
int ergebnis_row, ergebnis_col, ergebnis_block;
ergebnis_row = FALSE;
ergebnis_col = FALSE;
ergebnis_block = FALSE;

int row, col;
for (row = 1; row <= N*N; row++)
{
     if (check_row(row) == TRUE)
    {
         ergebnis_row = TRUE;
    }
}

if ((ergebnis_row && ergebnis_col && ergebnis_block) == FALSE)
    return FALSE;
else
    return TRUE;
}



bool check_row (int row)
{
    int tester[9], col, i, truefalse;
truefalse = 1;

for (col = 1; col <=(N*N); col++)
{
    tester[col] = 0; //Initialisierung von tester und temp
}            //


for (col = 1; col <=(N*N); col++)
{
    tester[matrix[row][col]] += 1; //For each number, tester array is increased by 1

}

for (col = 1; col <=(N*N); col++)
{

    if (tester[col] > 1)
    {   
        truefalse--; // If there is an error, truefalse changes
        printf("\nZu viele %d an Reihe %d", (matrix[row][col]), row);
    }

}

if (truefalse == 1)
    return FALSE;
else
    return TRUE;

}
```

Even though there is only 1 Argument 'row' in the function check_row, why does the compiler give an error about the number of the Arguments?

Comment: Look at the prototype for `check_row`, and compare to the definition of the function.

Comment: I can read, speak and write German -- but this is the English-speaking stackoverflow, so please translate your variable names!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function *declaration* does not match your function *call* or *definition*:

```
void check_row(void); // function declaration, specifies no arguments and no return value
...
if (check_row(row) == TRUE) // function call, passes 1 argument and uses return value
                            // conflicts with declaration
...
bool check_row (int row) // function definition, specifies bool return type and 1 int argument
                         // conflicts with declaration
```

You can save yourself some headaches by putting the *definition* of `check_row` before `main`, and not worry about needing a separate declaration.

Answer (score 2):

```
void check_row(void);
```

should be

```
bool check_row (int row);
```

Your declaration doesn't match the definition change your function declaration. Prototype should be changed